# How to make submenu appear to the left, instead of to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 menu, with a submenu.  The submenu displays to the right of the menu menu as expected.

However, the menu is on the far right of the screen.  So the menu is cut off on the right side.

Is there a way to make the menu appear on the left of the main menu, instead of to the right?

html:

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-user-menu">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown dropdown-menu dropdown-typical dropdown-menu-right">
                    <a repeat.for="item of statusTypes" click.delegate="editProgramStatus(item)" class="dropdown-item">${item.name}</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-more">
                        <div class="dropdown-more-caption">Choose color...</div>
                        <div class="dropdown-more-sub">
                            <div class="dropdown-more-sub-in">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-home"></span>Quant and Verbal</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-cart"></span>Real Gmat Test</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-speed"></span>Prep Official App</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-users"></span>CATprer Test</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-comments"></span>Third Party Test</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
```

css:

```
     .dropdown-menu {
  border-color: #d8e2e7;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem /*13/16*/;
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.dropdown-menu-col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.dropdown-header,
.dropdown-item {
  padding: 4px 12px;
}
.dropdown-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #6c7a86;
  font-size: 0.875rem /*14/16*/;
}
.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 0.9375rem /*15/16*/;
}
.dropdown-item .font-icon {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  color: #adb7be;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item.current {
  background: none;
  color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown-item:hover .font-icon,
.dropdown-item.current .font-icon {
  color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown-item.no-nowrap {
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #343434;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle:after,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle .font-icon {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle:after {
  color: #adb7be;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle .font-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 6px 0 0;
  color: #adb7be;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle-txt {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #00a8ff;
  font-size: 0.9375rem /*15/16*/;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle.dropdown-toggle-txt:after {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical.open a.dropdown-toggle,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical.open a.dropdown-toggle:after,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle:hover:after,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical.open a.dropdown-toggle .font-icon,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical a.dropdown-toggle:hover .font-icon {
  color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-header,
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-item {
  padding: 3px 14px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-item {
  font-size: 0.9375rem /*15/16*/;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 2px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more .dropdown-more-caption {
  padding: 3px 12px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more .dropdown-more-caption:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 0 4px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #adb7be;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more .dropdown-more-caption.padding {
  padding-left: 37px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more .dropdown-more-sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more .dropdown-more-sub-in {
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #d8e2e7;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more:hover .dropdown-more-caption {
  color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more:hover .dropdown-more-caption:before {
  border-left-color: #00a8ff;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-typical .dropdown-more:hover .dropdown-more-sub {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .btn.dropdown-toggle {
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem /*13/16*/;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-danger {
  background-color: #fa424a !important;
  border-color: #fa424a !important;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-color: #00a8ff !important;
  border-color: #00a8ff !important;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  background-color: #46c35f !important;
  border-color: #46c35f !important;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
  background-color: #f29824 !important;
  border-color: #f29824 !important;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .dropdown-menu {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-status .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item {
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
}
.dropdown-toggle .caret {
  display: none;
}
```

EDIT: I found this works well.

```
<div style="left: -95%;" class="dropdown-more-sub">
                        <div class="dropdown-more-sub-in">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-home"></span>Quant and Verbal</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-cart"></span>Real Gmat Test</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-speed"></span>Prep Official App</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-users"></span>CATprer Test</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="font-icon font-icon-comments"></span>Third Party Test</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dropdown-menu-right
```

You probably have to delete this class

Comment: Well, it makes sense, and I tried that, but it doesn't actually change the position of the submenu.

Comment: "Alignment
By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu."  

So maybe delete that class dropdown-menu-right

Comment: See the edit I just added.  By setting left to a negative, I was able to move it.  But this seems like a hack.  I couldn't seem to get dropdown-menu-left to have an effect.

Comment: I tried removing the dropdown-menu-right class as well, but it had no effect.

Comment: If you want to post an answer, I will accept.  Your answer lead me to what I finally used, so it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an interesting answer: set left to negative 95%.

This seems to work great.